# Can I say "砂糖ダイエット" ?

Tags: food

By "砂糖ダイエット" I mean diet based on heavy consumption of sweets.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is perfectly grammatical, but I haven't heard of such a method. Please make sure you really want to say 砂糖 (sugar) but not 糖質／炭水化物 (carbohydrate), because a few people actually seem to be talking about "(高)炭水化物ダイエット" (high-carb diets).